# How to split data passed from a .CSV file to a TestNG DataProvider

Tags: java, testng

Given my .csv data file in format `name:reference` :-

```
Johnson;464758,
Smith;839393,
Jones;940392,
Davidson;182939,
Arthurs;938494
```

And given my test code:

```
final static String DELIMITER = ",";

@DataProvider(name="references")
public Iterator<Object[]> refDataProvider(){
    try{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(CSV_FILE)).useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
        return new Iterator<Object[]>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return scanner.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public Object[] next() {
                return new Object[]{scanner.next()};
            }
        };
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}


@Test(dataProvider = "references")
public void submitNewCustomers(String reference){

    visit(customerHomePageUrl);
    customerHomepagePage().selectCustomer();

    customerSearchPage().typeInCustomerNumber(reference);

}
```

I only wish to pass the customer reference, *not* the name i.e. just `464758` to the DataProvider.  Is there a way I can split the file using a further delimiter on the semi-colon `;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply split while returning inside the overridden method `next()`

```
public class DpOne {
        final static String DELIMITER = ",";
    
        @DataProvider(name="references")
        public Iterator<Object[]> refDataProvider(){
            try{
              Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new File("temp.csv"));
              scanner.useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
              
                return new Iterator<Object[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return scanner.hasNext();
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public Object[] next() {
                        //apply split here
                        return new Object[]{scanner.next().split(";")[1]};
                    }
                };
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        
        @Test(dataProvider = "references")
        public void submitNewCustomers(String reference){
    
            System.out.print(reference);
        }
        
        
    
    }
```

Will display output as shown below

[image]